# Problema con input hidden formulario PHP

Tags: php, entrada

Tengo que hacer que un formulario básico incluido en una tabla envíe un determinado valor para luego poder borrar la fila, pero no soy capaz de que lo haga.

Se trata de una tabla con usuarios, claves y botones borrar (que utilizo como submit). La idea es que al presionar uno de ellos me guarde la variable $cont como el número de fila en el que estoy, pero siempre me devuelve o la primera, si utilizo al principio $cont=0, o la última, si uso $cont=1. ¿Hay alguna manera de que me guarde la fila en la que está el botón en concreto?

Adjunto código.

```
echo "<table align='center'><form action='' method='post'>
            <tr><th>USUARIO</th><th colspan='2'>CLAVE ENCRIPTADA</th>"; 
    $cont=0;
    foreach ($usuarios as $clave=>$valor) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$usuarios[$clave]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$pswds[$clave]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$cont."</td>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='cont' value='".$cont."'>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='borrar' value='BORRAR' id='enviar'/></td>";
        $cont++;
    }
    echo "</form></table>";
```

Comment: No me parece optimo incluir un formulario, es código extra completamente innecesario, simplemente remplaza el `input` por un `button` y le pasas el `id` de tu registro como `value`, luego con `javascript` o `jquery` captura el evento click del boton y trabaja ese value como creas necesario

Comment: como comenta @Kevin deberías meter el valor en el boton. De todas formas, si culegas tu función de captura de datos (o como los recoges) quizás podamos ayudarte mas.
PD: no suele ser correcto tener varios submit en el mismo sitio, por lo que eso, mejor buttons y capturar la acción con un función JS.

Comment: ¡Hola! Lo cierto es que no tengo la opción de hacerlo sin el formulario, y tampoco añadir JS, tiene que ser todo en PHP. La recogida de datos la hago con una función con un $_POST['cont'] dentro, que es como llamo al input hidden. Lo que sí es cierto es que tengo la opción de sustituir los botones por links, aunque tampoco entiendo muy bien cómo lalamr a la función.

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no puedes usar Javascript? ¿Es un ejercicio, JS está prohibido en tu entorno... o por qué? Viendo que creas el `input` en un bucle, cometes un grave error, porque siempre la asignas el mismo `id` y en un HTML ningún elemento puede tener ids repetidos, es incorrecto aunque funcione. Como se ha comentado, puedes usar el `id` u otra etiqueta para diferenciar cada fila y luego con Javascript determinas la fila que es mediante un *listener*. No veo otra forma mejor de poder hacerlo. Puede ser con links, pero vas a sobrecargar innecesariamente.

Comment: No puedo usar JS porque es un problema con un ejercicio, y solo tengo permitido PHP. El botón/link debe tener la funcionalidad de borrar un solo usuario más tarde en un CSV, pero claro, necesito seleccionar la línea concreta primero.